Vertical scrollbar appears when it's not necessary
In the snippet below, the horizontal scrollbar is appearing as expected. However I don't understand why the vertical scrollbar appears as well.
Because the child and the parent have the same height, no vertical scrollbar should be necessary.
What I want is that the vertical scrollbar only appears when the child height exceeds the parents height


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#root {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto; /* Show horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Show vertical scrollbar only if content overflows vertically */
}

#root2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px; /* Wider than parent to show horizontal scrollbar */
  height: 400px; /* Same height as parent initially */
}
<div id="root"><div id="root2"></div></div>




I turned the provided code into a snippet and see no horizontal scroll bar (in Brave on Mac - also tested Safari)? Cannot replicate.

because the horizontal scrollbar is added to the height making the vertical one appears (not all the browsers will do this)

@somethinghere Horizontal scrollbar is visible on Firefox 133.0.3 (64-bit) - Windows

@DarkBee But is the vertical one? Cause the horizontal one was intentional!

Can confirm the vertical isn't visible on Firefox - However your initial comment stated: "see no horizontal scroll bar" which was probably a typo then

@DarkBee Ah yes, I did see the horizontal one and not the vertical one. Brain fart!

The problem is that the horizontal and vertical scroll bar breadth is 20px, approx.
The scroll bars are adding extra height as well as width to the div.
If you remove the horizontal scroll bar, it is fully okay in the code below:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#root {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Show horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Show vertical scrollbar only if content overflows vertically */
}

#root2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px; /* Wider than parent to show horizontal scrollbar */
  height: 400px; /* Same height as parent initially */
}
<div id="root"><div id="root2"></div></div>



(CHECK IT IN FULL PAGE)
The solution is to make the height auto in the parent container.
OR
add an extra height in the parent container.
I don't recommend the second option because the scroll bar height differs in other web browsers.
I hope this helps you.

100% to take the size of the parent container instead.
#root2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px; /* Wider than parent to show horizontal scrollbar */
    height: 100%; /* Same height as parent initially */
}

